# compile NETCONF for beaglebone (ARM)

Tags: arm, pthreads, ietf-netconf

I need to compile libnetconf from https://github.com/CESNET/libnetconf for beaglebone. But the configure script gives error and exits.
last part of the log is

```
checking for xmlDOMWrapReconcileNamespaces in -lxml2... no
checking for xslt-config... yes
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no
checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work with -mthreads... no
checking for the pthreads library -lpthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with --thread-safe... no
checking whether pthreads work with -mt... no
checking for pthread-config... no
configure: error: Missing POSIX threads support.
```

configure was run as follows

```
./configure --build=x86_64-linux   --host=arm-linux-gnueabi   --target=arm-linux-gnueabi   --prefix=/usr   --exec_prefix=/usr   --bindir=/usr/bin   --sbindir=/usr/sbin   --libexecdir=/usr/lib/libnetconf   --datadir=/usr/share   --sysconfdir=/etc   --sharedstatedir=/com   --localstatedir=/var   --libdir=/usr/lib   --includedir=/usr/include   --oldincludedir=/usr/include   --infodir=/usr/share/info   --mandir=/usr/share/man  --disable-libssh
```

libpthreads is present. What am i missing?

Comment: Where exactly is libpthreads present?  If you're looking at your x86 host system's version, that's clearly not going to help for a cross-compile.

Comment: libpthread-2.19.so
libpthread.a
libpthread_nonshared.a
libpthread.so
libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.19.so
are present in
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/

Comment: OK. Since I don't know anything about netconf, I don't know which of those paths being given to configure represent run-time stuff vs. build-time stuff, but the likes of `libdir` and `includedir` apparently pointing to your host machine's files (rather than the cross-toolchain or a mounted target filesystem) raises a bit of a red flag.